# how to enable sqlite3 for php?

Tags: php, sqlite

I am trying to install sqlite3 for PHP in Ubuntu.

I install `apt-get php5-sqlite3` and edited `php.ini` to include sqlite3 extension.

When I run `phpinfo();` I get

```
SQLITE3
SQLite3 support  enabled  
sqlite3 library version  3.4.2
```

as shown above, `sqlite3` is enabled. However, I get "Class SQLite3 not found" when I use

```
 new SQLite3("database");
```

Comment: Useful resource: https://zetcode.com/php/sqlite3/

Answer (score 40, accepted):

**Edit: This answer is outdated, but can't be removed because it's accepted. Please see the solution from Stacey Richards for the correct answer.**

```
 sudo apt-get install php5-cli php5-dev make
 sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-0 libsqlite3-dev
 sudo apt-get install php5-sqlite3
 sudo apt-get remove php5-sqlite3
 cd ~
 wget http://pecl.php.net/get/sqlite3-0.6.tgz
 tar -zxf sqlite3-0.6.tgz
 cd sqlite3-0.6/
 sudo phpize
 sudo ./configure
 sudo make
 sudo make install
 sudo apache2ctl restart
```

Ripped from the [ubuntu form](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=891767).

Comment: The 2nd to last command should be `sudo checkinstall` (after running `sudo apt-get install checkinstall`. Why use an OS with a package manager if you're not going to use it?

Comment: this is now out dated advice.  e.g. http://forum.linode.com/viewtopic.php?p=39974

Comment: Best advice for this understandably annoying situation: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276564/2778484 and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78438/blatantly-wrong-accepted-answer (fixing the answer with an edit is obviously not possible since it's beyond just a syntax error).

Comment: It is `apt-get install php5-sqlite` today as of 2015

Comment: As of 2021: `sudo apt-get install php-sqlite3`

Answer (score 238):

Try:

```
apt-get install php5-sqlite
```

That worked for me.

Comment: the php5-sqlite3 package doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: Or, in the case of CentOS, `sudo yum install php-sqlite3 -y`

Comment: This also added a PHP configuration file in /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d; it even restarted Apache, although for some reason I had to restart it again for the change to take effect.

Comment: Or, in case of Ubuntu 16.0.4 Xenial, `sudo apt install php-sqlite3`

Comment: Good answer but I needed to restart apache to get the module to show up (eg. `sudo service apache2 restart`)

Answer (score 45):

For PHP7, alter the below for your version of PHP (7.0, 7.2, 7.4, etc) and run

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-sqlite3
```

and restart Apache

```
sudo apache2ctl restart
```

Comment: for php 7.2    `sudo apt-get install php7.2-sqlite`

Comment: E: Unable to locate package php7.3-sqlite3

Answer (score 16):

For Ubuntu 18.04 and PHP 7.2:

`sudo apt install php-sqlite3`

Comment: You mat need to execute `apt-get update` before the command above to make it executed with no errors.

Answer (score 15):

The accepted answer is not complete without the remainder of instructions (paraphrased below) from the [forum thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=891767) linked to:

```
cd /etc/php5/conf.d

cat > sqlite3.ini
# configuration for php SQLite3 module
extension=sqlite3.so
^D

sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Comment: I thought you also had to modify the php.conf file?

Comment: At least on Ubuntu 14.04, this step is not needed, as there already is a `sqlite3.ini` as `/etc/php5/mods-available/sqlite3.ini`

Answer (score 5):

The Debian/Ubuntu way for php-7.2, php-7.3 & php-7.4 (e.g. the `[234]` part)

```sh
sudo apt install php7.[234]-sqlite
sudo phpenmod sqlite3
```

Be sure to note that on Windows Subsystem for Linux version 1 (WSL1) the (file-)locking system for SQlite is broken.

Answer (score 4):

The SQLite3 PDO driver is named SQLite, not SQLite3, so you can do:

```
new SQLite("database");
```

For a SQLite2 database:

```
new SQLite2("database");
```

Answer (score 3):

one thing I want to add , before you try to  install

```
apt-get install php5-sqlite
```

or

```
apt-get install php5-sqlite3
```

search the given package is available or not :-

```
 # apt-cache search 'php5'
```

After that you get :-

```
php5-rrd - rrd module for PHP 5

php5-sasl - Cyrus SASL extension for PHP 5

php5-snmp - SNMP module for php5

**php5-sqlite - SQLite module for php5**

php5-svn - PHP Bindings for the Subversion Revision control system

php5-sybase - Sybase / MS SQL Server module for php5
```

Here you get an idea about whether your version support or not ..
in my system I get **php5-sqlite - SQLite module for php5**
so I prefer to install

```
**apt-get install php5-sqlite**
```

Answer (score 3):

For Ubuntu 20.04 and PHP 8.2:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install php8.2-sqlite3
sudo phpenmod pdo_sqlite
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt-get install php5-cli php5-dev make

sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-0 libsqlite3-dev

sudo apt-get install php5-sqlite3

sudo apt-get remove php5-sqlite3

cd ~

wget http://pecl.php.net/get/sqlite3-0.6.tgz

tar -zxf sqlite3-0.6.tgz

cd sqlite3-0.6/

sudo phpize

sudo ./configure
```

That worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove php5*
sudo apt-get install php5 php5-sqlite php5-mysql
sudo apt-get install php-pear php-apc php5-curl
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get install php5-sqlite
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-fastcgi php5-fpm php5
```

Comment: I guess OP needs to know some config changes. Just installing the required software doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Careful with these commands! While this could actually work it would be useful to inform that **this will remove and purge** all packages starting with "php5". In other words it will remove both core files and configuration files.

Comment: this worked for me!!!  The cleaning out and then re installing all these things was good.... except for the second to last command  install php-sqlite..... that's the same thing that happens in the 2nd command?  Maybe it's needed in certain cases, but it didn't seem to do anything for me

Answer (score 1):

In Centos 6.7, in my case the library file /usr/lib64/php/modules/sqlite3.so was missing.

```
yum install php-pdo 

vim /etc/php.d/sqlite3.ini
; Enable sqlite3 extension module
extension=sqlite3.so

sudo service httpd restart
```

Answer (score 1):

Only use:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-sqlite
```

and later

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 1):

For Debian distributions. Nothing worked for until I added the debian main repositories on the apt sources (I don't know how were they removed):
`sudo vi /etc/apt/sources.list`

and added

```
deb  http://deb.debian.org/debian  stretch main
deb-src  http://deb.debian.org/debian  stretch main
```

after that `sudo apt-get update` (you can upgrade too) and finally `sudo apt-get install php-sqlite3`

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the version of PHP. For php7.0 the following commands work:
`sudo apt-get install php7.0-sqlite3`
then restart the Apache server:
`sudo service apache2 restart`

Answer (score 0):

This will drown here, but I fixed my problems with this:

As far as I have found out, there is a faulty file in `/usr/local/lib` called `libsqlite3.so.0` which points to `libsqlite3.so.0.8.6`. It's been installed through the php7.3-* packages as far as I can tell.

I renamed the file in case it was needed for something. With the command:

`cd /usr/local/lib`
`sudo mv libsqlite3.so.0 ./libsqlite3.so.0.back`

But you can also just delete it:
`rm libsqlite3.so.0`

The thread that lead me to the answer: [link](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1505101)

This solved my problems, and I hope they solve yours as well :)

Answer (score 0):

make sure servers' php.ini file has
extension=php_sqlite3.dll enabled
and you have write rules for website root file