# Enable SQLite3 in PHP 5

Tags: php, sqlite, debian

I am trying to install sqlite3 for php5.2 in debian. in php 5.3 sqlite3 is enable but in debian php 5.2 is the last stable version! Can I enable and use sqlite3 even so?

Comment: Should be moved to ServerFault.com.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/948899/how-to-enable-sqlite3-for-php

Comment: Also on ServerFault: http://serverfault.com/questions/32982/how-do-i-enable-sqlite-on-linux-apache-php

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the package [php5-sqlite](http://packages.debian.org/lenny/php5-sqlite).

Comment: thats sqlite! i need sqlite3 :(

Comment: and debian, not ubuntu.. there isn't a duplicate!

Comment: Are you sure you've added the comments correctly? And what exactly is your problem with the package I linked to?