# LInux: How to install FTS3 (for sqlite3) in PHP?

Tags: php, linux, sqlite, installation, fts3

I tried asking the question [php - Is there a binary package for php5-sqlite3 with fts3 enabled? - Ask Ubuntu - Stack Exchange](https://askubuntu.com/questions/52094/is-there-a-binary-package-for-php5-sqlite3-with-fts3-enabled); but no dice there - so I'll try here again in different words: how can one enable FTS3 under SQLite3 for php on an Ubuntu Linux server?

I would want to enable FTS3 for a Mediawiki using Sqlite - and I  typically get the "`no such module: fts3`" error.

I have found:

- [how to enable sqlite3 for php? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948899/how-to-enable-sqlite3-for-php) - where it is recommended that `php5-sqlite3` is removed and sqlite3 is installed from source (though no specific mention of FTS3)
- [Old Nabble - SQLite - FTS3 indexing in PHP < 5.3](http://old.nabble.com/FTS3-indexing-in-PHP-%3C-5.3-td30500563.html) which says:

> > and here is the error:
>   >
>   > 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such module: fts3'
>   >
>
> There is a compile-time option:  SQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3

... which, I guess, eventually says that there is no other way to activate FTS3 for SQlite3 for PHP - other than building sqlite for php from source? That would not be a good option for me, since I have no rights on the production server... which is why I'd ask again: is there some sort of a binary package to help me get FTS3 enabled?

If there isn't a binary package for that - I imagine the sqlite3 part for php will be compiled as an `.so` object. Is there a way to persuade PHP to, somehow, load an "external" `.so` just for a particular server directory (akin to how [ini_set](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) is used to change `display_errors` locally)?

EDIT: Bonus question: Say I've installed sqlite3 with FTS3 enabled from source; will PHP show some sort of a message/indication in `phpinfo()`, and what will that message be?

Thanks in advance for any answers,
Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use answer from [how to enable sqlite3 for php? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948899/how-to-enable-sqlite3-for-php) but instead of

```
$ sudo ./configure
```

you need

```
$ sudo CPPFLAGS="-DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3_PARENTHESIS" ./configure
```

Credits to: [sqlite - fts3 manual](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_2). Just to clarify, you don't need install separate php5-sqlite3 package because if you look into http://pecl.php.net/get/sqlite3-0.6.tgz you will see that php_sqlite3 included there. Btw, important line from INSTALL file:

> Make sure you have extension=sqlite3.so in your php.ini

Comment: Thanks for that @Zyava - I would have never found those switches :) And I guess that confirms there is **no** binary package to enable this... By the way, any ideas on how could I check for proper installation (beyond running a page and not getting an error message)? Would some message be shown in `phpinfo()`?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to recompile the sqlite extension. You can load an extension as:

```
<?php
$db = new SQLite3('mysqlitedb.db');
$db->loadExtension('myExtension.so');
?>
```

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.loadextension.php