# XAMPP Php SQLite3 no such module: fts3- ubuntu server 12.04 X86

Tags: php, sqlite, xampp

I tried google and find two articles about it.

And with the sqlite introduction link http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_2

I used XAMPP Development package and download the php-5.4.7.tar.gz(https://www.php.net/distributions/php-5.4.7.tar.gz) try to compilatie the sqlite3.

But when I cd into php-5.4.7\ext\sqlite3 and use /opt/lampp/bin/phpize
It shows about "can not find config.m4. Make sure that you run '/opt/lampp/bin/phpize' in the top level source directory of the module". I'm sure I had already in the top level source directory of the module...

Is there some knows what I can do to solve it? Please give me some advice. Thank you for your help^_^

Here are two articles I found but I think they are useless for my problem:
[LInux: How to install FTS3 (for sqlite3) in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6754212/linux-how-to-install-fts3-for-sqlite3-in-php)
[how to enable sqlite3 for php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948899/how-to-enable-sqlite3-for-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.download xampp-linux-devel-1.8.1.tar.gz

```
tar xf xampp-linux-devel-1.8.1.tar.gz -C /opt
```

2.download php-5.4.16.tar.gz

```
tar xf php-5.4.16.tar.gz -C /opt
cd php-5.4.15。
./configure --prefix=/opt/lampp/php-5.4.15 --enable-fpm --with-apxs2=/opt/lampp/bin/apxs --with-mysql=mysqlnd --with-zlib=yes --with-zlib-dir=/opt/lampp --with-mysql-sock=/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock --enable-mbstring=all --with-curl=/opt/lampp --enable-mbregex --with-mysqli=mysqlnd --with-iconv --with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd --with-pdo-sqlite --with-libxml-dir=/opt/lampp
make
sudo make install
/opt/lampp/lampp restart
```

This solution from my colleague GF→http://gfzj.us/
But he doesn't write the detail.

If you need more detail, you can see my blog shipengliang.com/software-exp/关于xampp使用sqlite3-报错sqlite3-no-such-module-fts3的解决办法.html#Englishversion