# Compiling Sqlite and including it in PHP

Tags: sqlite

I compiled Sqlite 3.7.13 using:

```
apt-get install build-essential
apt-get install php5-dev
wget http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite-autoconf-3071300.tar.gz
tar -xzf sqlite-autoconf-3071300.tar.gz
cd sqlite-autoconf-3071300
phpize
./configure
make
make install
ldconfig
sqlite3 --version
```

Edited sqlite.ini and included sqlite.so

```
nano /etc/php5/conf.d/sqlite.ini
extionsion=sqlite.so
```

The problem is that now I cannot see sqlite extension in my phpinfo and sqlite is not working in PHP scripts. I m using Debian 6.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're doing most stuff correctly.

SUGGESTIONS:

1. Is this a typo: `extionsion=sqlite.so`?

   SHOULD BE: `extension=sqlite.so`
2. Is your sqlite.so in your PHP plugins directory?
3. Look at this link:

   - [how to enable sqlite3 for php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948899/how-to-enable-sqlite3-for-php)
4. Also look here:

   - http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite.installation.php