# Testing Controllers in Symfony2 with Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, symfony-2.1

I have created a very simple REST controller in Symony2 with Database insert/updates/deletes in the controller actions.

Is there a nice way to write unit/integration tests for these controller actions without polluting the production database? Do I have to work with different environments - or is there a proposed way from the framework vendor for this?

Current Controller Example:

```
public function postAction()
{
    $json = $this->getRequest()->getContent();
    $params = json_decode($json);
    $name = $params->name;
    $description = $params->description;

    $sandbox = new Sandbox();
    $sandbox->setName($name);
    $sandbox->setDescription($description);
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($sandbox);
    $em->flush();

    $response = new Response('/sandbox/'.$sandbox->getId());
    $response->setStatusCode(201);
    return $response;
}
```

Current Test Example:

```
class SandboxControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{

    public function testRest()
    {
        $client = static::createClient();

        $crawler = $client->request('POST', '/service/sandbox', array(), array(), array(), json_encode(array('name' => 'TestMe', 'description' => 'TestDesc')));

        $this->assertEquals(
                201, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode()
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: You should definitely not run unit test on a production database. You should have a test database instead!

Comment: @j0k That's true! I am not sure how the development and deployment process  in Symfony2 would look like. How can I tell phpunit which database environment to use in Symfony2...?

Comment: Check [the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/testing.html), specially the part about *Testing Configuration* at the end.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In my opinion you should definitely avoid change database with your tests.

My favourite way to achieve this is inject entity manager mock inside a test client. For example:

```
public function testRest()
{
    // create entity manager mock
    $entityManagerMock = $this->getMockBuilder('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager')
        ->setMethods(array('persist', 'flush'))
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();

    // now you can get some assertions if you want, eg.:
    $entityManagerMock->expects($this->once())
        ->method('flush');

    // next you need inject your mocked em into client's service container
    $client = static::createClient();
    $client->getContainer()->set('doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager', $entityManagerMock);

    // then you just do testing as usual
    $crawler = $client->request('POST', '/service/sandbox', array(), array(), array(), json_encode(array('name' => 'TestMe', 'description' => 'TestDesc')));

    $this->assertEquals(
            201, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode()
    );
}
```

One thing with this solution which you should be aware is that you need inject your mocked service before each request. This is because the client reboots a kernel between each request (which means that the container is rebuild as well).

**edit:**

My GET approach in controller's tests is that I can mock entity repositories and so on in order to stub every getting data from db but it's a lot of work and it's not very comfortable, so I prefer in this case (I mean only if we speak about controller's test) actually getting real data from db. By real data I mean data created with doctrine fixtures. And as long as we don't change database we can depend on the fixtures.

But if we are speaking about changing data inside db (POST/PUT/DELETE methods) I always use mocks. If you'll use em mock and set appropriate expectations on "perist" and "flush" methods, you can be sure that the data is correctly created/updated/deleted actually without any database's modifications.

Comment: I like! But how would I test PUT/DELETE/GET requests when there is not actually a representation? For example GET /service/sandbox/1 should get the sandbox with ID 1. In my database oriented thinking I would first create the resource and the GET/PUT and DELETE it.

Comment: Okay - I must do some reading on Mock Objects - but this can work perfectly! Thanks!

Comment: I've edited my answer, I hope this bring some more clarifications. Best! :)

Comment: Tried and... Like a charm! Didn't realize you can also `set` services programmatically. I always used the container to `get` them and only established them a) in the config files and b) in unit testing (without container, just passing the mock to the constructor that needs it). Good trick to fake the kernel in functional tests, sure this is useful in many other controller tests, like preventing to send mails or preventing to access a remote service. This hack eases functional testing a lot!!! Thnx @Cyprian

Comment: Hey worked but it now fails, if I add FOSUserBundle and HWIOAuthBundle!!! it says `PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getRepository() on a non-object in /files/custom_www/antique-crayon/preproduction/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php on line 759` - If I stop injecting the `doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager` (and comment out the expects once, of course) then it gives green bar (of course then saving to the real DB which is what we wanted to avoid)

Comment: This is ok for simple controllers. But in general mocking EM escalates too quickly. So you better go with a proper test env.

Comment: In case any one gets this error "LogicException : You must set the KERNEL_CLASS environment variable to the fully-qualified class name of your Kernel in phpunit.xml / phpunit.xml.dist or override the InspectionControllerTest::createKernel() or InspectionControllerTest::getKernelClass() method.
"
I solved this by adding 
  protected static function getKernelClass()
    {
        return 'App\Kernel';
    }

Answer (score 4):

Here is what I do

in your test class add the $kernel static variable and create a function that loads the kernel in test mode

```
protected static $kernel;
protected static $container;

public static function setUpBeforeClass()
{
    self::$kernel = new \AppKernel('test', true);
    self::$kernel->boot();

    self::$container = self::$kernel->getContainer();
}
```

And as the first line of test function ,call `self:setUpBeforeClass()`

This makes symfony load the config_test.yml configuration file and you can define a different database connection there

Answer (score 1):

A good way to do this, especially if you need to have some test data in your database is using a separate SQLite Database together with the DoctrineFixturesBundle.

- [Here is how to install the FixturesBundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html)
- [A clean way to set up your Fixtures and Tests](http://vincent.composieux.fr/article/test-your-doctrine-repository-using-a-sqlite-database)

  [Make sure you have the SQLite extension activated in your php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948899/how-to-enable-sqlite3-for-php)