# Disable DB write in testing controller - injecting doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager throws "Fatal error" when activating FOSUser and HWIOAuth

Tags: unit-testing, doctrine-orm, fosuserbundle, entitymanager, hwioauthbundle

I want to disable the DB writing when functional testing a controller in phpunit.

In a project in Symfony2, I use phpunit to test a POST call to an API endpoint that saves to database. This worked and I now have a regression problem when activating `FOSUser` + `HWIOAuth`.

To avoid the phpunit writing dummy data to the database, I use this trick here: [Testing Controllers in Symfony2 with Doctrine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14414393/testing-controllers-in-symfony2-with-doctrine) to mock the entity manager, then inject the mocked service into the container of the testing system.

This way when you run the test, the DB endpoint is mocked and it is only tested that a flush() is called thanks to the `$entityManagerMock->expects($this->once())->method('flush');` that you can see in that question and in the code below.

**This used to work.**

This test gave green bar, POST calls were tested and no data was saved to the database.

```php
public function testPostCreatesIssue()
{
    $client = static::createClient();
    
    $entityManagerMock = $this->getMockBuilder( 'Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager' )
        ->setMethods( array( 'persist', 'flush' ) )
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();
    
    $entityManagerMock->expects( $this->once() )
        ->method( 'flush' );
    
    $client->getContainer()->set( 'doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager', $entityManagerMock );
    
    $postData = array
    (
        'title' => 'Issues controller test, post creates issue',
        'body' => 'The test tests that a post call' . PHP_EOL . 'creates a new issue' . PHP_EOL . 'in the database.' . PHP_EOL . 'UTF8: áéíóú àèìòù ñç',
        'pageUrl' => 'file://Xmontero/AntiqueCrayon/MainBundle/Tests/Controller/IssuesControllerTest.php'
    );
    $crawler = $client->request( 'POST', '/issues/', $postData );
    $response = $client->getResponse();
    
    $this->assertEquals( Response::HTTP_CREATED, $response->getStatusCode() );
    $this->assertEquals( 'application/json', $response->headers->get( 'content-type' ) );
}
```

At that moment, I only had the default bundles + my own bundles in the `AppKernel.php`

**The problem**

When I activate those bundles in the `AppKernel.php`

```
new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),
new HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\HWIOAuthBundle(),
```

and after configuration, everything works properly testing manually in my browser, including the ajax call that does the POST tested above. That controller has nothing to do with the FOSUser and HWIOAuth as that controller worked before I activated those bundles in the kernel.

But despite the manual test did work, the automated test started to fail giving `Call to a member function getRepository() on a non-object` not in a line of my code but in the very internals of the FOS and the Doctrine - here's the full output:

```
xavi@bromo:/files/custom_www/antique-crayon/preproduction$ phpunit -c app --filter Post src/Xmontero/AntiqueCrayon/MainBundle/Tests/Controller/IssuesControllerTest.php
PHPUnit 3.6.10 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Configuration read from /files/custom_www/antique-crayon/preproduction/app/phpunit.xml.dist

PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getRepository() on a non-object in /files/custom_www/antique-crayon/preproduction/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php on line 759
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /usr/bin/phpunit:0
PHP   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() /usr/bin/phpunit:46
PHP   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:130
PHP   4. PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner->doRun() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:192
PHP   5. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/TestRunner.php:325
PHP   6. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->runTest() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Framework/TestSuite.php:745
PHP   7. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->run() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Framework/TestSuite.php:772
PHP   8. PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult->run() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php:751
PHP   9. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runBare() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Framework/TestResult.php:649
PHP  10. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runTest() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php:804
PHP  11. ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs() /usr/share/php/PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php:942
PHP  12. Xmontero\AntiqueCrayon\MainBundle\Tests\Controller\IssuesControllerTest->testPostCreatesIssue() /files/custom_www/antique-crayon/preproduction/src/Xmontero/AntiqueCrayon/MainBundle/Tests/Controller/IssuesControllerTest.php:0
PHP  13. Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Client->request() /files/custom_www/antique-crayon/preproduction/src/Xmontero/AntiqueCrayon/MainBundle/Tests/Controller/IssuesControllerTest.php:41
PHP  14. Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Client->doRequest() /files/custom_www/antique-crayon/preproduction/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/BrowserKit/Client.php:327
PHP  15. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Client->doRequest() /files/custom_www/antique-crayon/preproduction/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Client.php:111
PHP  16. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle() /files/custom_www/antique-crayon/preproduction/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Client.php:81
PHP  17. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareHttpKernel->handle() /files/custom_www/antique-crayon/preproduction/app/bootstrap.php.cache:2330
PHP  18. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle() /files/custom_www/antique-crayon/preproduction/app/bootstrap.php.cache:3080
PHP  19. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw() /files/custom_www/antique-crayon/preproduction/app/bootstrap.php.cache:2931
PHP  20. Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\TraceableEventDispatcher->dispatch() /files/custom_www/antique-crayon/preproduction/app/bootstrap.php.cache:2958
PHP  21. Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\TraceableEventDispatcher->preProcess() /files/custom_www/antique-crayon/preproduction/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/Debug/TraceableEventDispatcher.php:107
PHP  22. Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->getListeners() /files/custom_www/antique-crayon/preproduction/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/Debug/TraceableEventDispatcher.php:215
PHP  23. Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->lazyLoad() /files/custom_www/antique-crayon/preproduction/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/ContainerAwareEventDispatcher.php:128
PHP  24. Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get() /files/custom_www/antique-crayon/preproduction/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/ContainerAwareEventDispatcher.php:188
PHP  25. appTestDebugProjectContainer->getProfilerListenerService() /files/custom_www/antique-crayon/preproduction/app/bootstrap.php.cache:2056
PHP  26. Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get() /files/custom_www/antique-crayon/preproduction/app/cache/test/appTestDebugProjectContainer.php:2251
PHP  27. appTestDebugProjectContainer->getProfilerService() /files/custom_www/antique-crayon/preproduction/app/bootstrap.php.cache:2056
PHP  28. Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get() /files/custom_www/antique-crayon/preproduction/app/cache/test/appTestDebugProjectContainer.php:2234
PHP  29. appTestDebugProjectContainer->getSecurity_ContextService() /files/custom_www/antique-crayon/preproduction/app/bootstrap.php.cache:2056
PHP  30. Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get() /files/custom_www/antique-crayon/preproduction/app/cache/test/appTestDebugProjectContainer.php:2374
PHP  31. appTestDebugProjectContainer->getSecurity_Authentication_ManagerService() /files/custom_www/antique-crayon/preproduction/app/bootstrap.php.cache:2056
PHP  32. Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get() /files/custom_www/antique-crayon/preproduction/app/cache/test/appTestDebugProjectContainer.php:3941
PHP  33. appTestDebugProjectContainer->getFosUser_UserProvider_UsernameEmailService() /files/custom_www/antique-crayon/preproduction/app/bootstrap.php.cache:2056
PHP  34. Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get() /files/custom_www/antique-crayon/preproduction/app/cache/test/appTestDebugProjectContainer.php:3885
PHP  35. appTestDebugProjectContainer->getFosUser_UserManagerService() /files/custom_www/antique-crayon/preproduction/app/bootstrap.php.cache:2056
PHP  36. FOS\UserBundle\Doctrine\UserManager->__construct() /files/custom_www/antique-crayon/preproduction/app/cache/test/appTestDebugProjectContainer.php:1657
PHP  37. Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager->getRepository() /files/custom_www/antique-crayon/preproduction/vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/FOS/UserBundle/Doctrine/UserManager.php:40
xavi@bromo:/files/custom_www/antique-crayon/preproduction$
```

**Narrowing down the problem**

The problem is the service `doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager` for which I inject a mock during the test phase, this is why the manual test in the browser does not fail: No mocks, there.

If I edit my test to do not use any mock, just write to the real DB, it then works:

To test without mock I just comment out the `->set()` in the container. And to avoid an `Method was expected to be called 1 times, actually called 0 times.` I also comment out the `->expects()`:

```
    //$entityManagerMock->expects( $this->once() )
    //  ->method( 'flush' );
    //
    //$client->getContainer()->set( 'doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager', $entityManagerMock );
```

then the tests greenbars:

```
xavi@bromo:/files/custom_www/antique-crayon/preproduction$ phpunit -c app --filter Post src/Xmontero/AntiqueCrayon/MainBundle/Tests/Controller/IssuesControllerTest.php
PHPUnit 3.6.10 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Configuration read from /files/custom_www/antique-crayon/preproduction/app/phpunit.xml.dist

.

Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 32.50Mb

OK (1 test, 2 assertions)
xavi@bromo:/files/custom_www/antique-crayon/preproduction$
```

**Conclusions**

- Injecting a mock in `doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager` pre-activating FOSUser and HWIOAuth, works fine
- When activating these bundles in the `AppKernel` the trick does not work.
- I then only can test allowing to write real data to a database, which is not desired when testing.

**Question**

How can I disable the writing to the DataBase when calling a controller from a test in phpunit, when FOSUserBundle and HWIOAuthBundle are activated in the kernel?

Thanks!
Xavi.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not proud about it but I haven't done so many test with phpUnit to answer your question with a 100% of security on the answer, but here is my opinion.

I think that the solution is to mock the entityManager, as you are doing yet, but you are moking only the persist() and flush() method.

```
->setMethods( array( 'persist', 'flush' ) )
->disableOriginalConstructor()
```

Without the code you are trying to test I can't know it for sure, but it seems that in any part of your controller you're using de FOSUserBundle or the HWIOAuthBundle and one or both of them is using at least the getRepository() method and you need to mock at least all the methods that can be used via FOSUserBundle and HWIOAuthBundle.

If you don't indicate the methods with the setMethods() all of them are mocked, and you can still have controll with the number of times a method is called or not as in the code example below.

```
$mockObjectManager = $this->getMockBuilder('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager')
    ->disableOriginalConstructor()
    ->getMock();

$mockObjectManager->expects($this->any())
    ->method('persist');
$mockObjectManager->expects($this->atLeastOnce())
    ->method('flush');
```

If the FOSUserBundle is trying to get the repository, as it seems, you will have to mock the return of that call, if you don't do that it will probably end with an error at the next call, an example:

```
$this->em->expects($this->any())
        ->method('getRepository')
        ->with('FOSUserBundle:XXXXX')
        ->will($this->returnValue($this->getMockedClassWithFind('\Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository')));
```

I think the best solution is to start resolving this first error, you will see another error because the object the FosUserBundle is expecting will be null, and mock that one, and maybe expects another object or maybe you're done.

Hope is helpful.