# How to mock doctrine service for controller action when doctrine is used elsewhere

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

I have a controller action that contains some code like the following:

```
$repository = $this->get("doctrine")->getRepository(User::class);
$user = $repository->findOneBy(array('username' => $request->request->get("username")));
```

I wanted to mock the repository. At first I wasn't sure how to do that, but then I found this SO post: [Testing Controllers in Symfony2 with Doctrine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14414393/testing-controllers-in-symfony2-with-doctrine)

From the answer there, I surmised that I should create a mock of the doctrine service AND the repository object, and tell the mockbuilder that the repository object returns the entity I want to test. Then I should replace the doctrine service using the following line of code:

```
$client->getContainer()->set("doctrine", $doctrineMockObject);
```

and then make the request:

```
$client->request("POST", "/checkUsername");
```

The problem with this is that there is a twig template that actually calls a separate controller action, and that action uses doctrine as well. So that causes the application to break since it is using the mock doctrine object I injected into the container.

Is there any way to only use the mock doctrine service for the action that I am testing? Otherwise, is there any alternative method to do what I want to do? I am out of ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As 'alternative method' you can stop using Container as Service Locator and instead of injecting it everywhere inject only services that you need into controllers/other services.

Comment: You are right. Unfortunately the documentation for Symfony2, which I was using at the time, heavily demonstrated using the locator pattern. I have since upgraded to Symfony4 which has moved away from the locator pattern.