# PHP5 and sqlite not working

Tags: php, sqlite, ubuntu-12.04

I have followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948899/how-to-enable-sqlite3-for-php) and [this](http://zetcode.com/db/sqlitephp/) but the page doesnt load when I try to use sqlite.

Here is what my phpinfo() looks like regarding the added extensions:

```
etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini, /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/10-pdo.ini, 

/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-curl.ini, /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-gd.ini, 

/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-intl.ini, /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-memcache.ini, 

/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-mysql.ini, /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini, 

/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini, /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-pdo_sqlite.ini, 

/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-pspell.ini, /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-recode.ini, 

/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-snmp.ini, /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-sqlite3.ini, 

/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-tidy.ini, /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-xcache.ini, 

/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-xmlrpc.ini, /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-xsl.ini, 

/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/imagick.ini, /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/imap.ini, 

/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/mcrypt.ini, /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/ming.ini, 

/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/ps.ini
```

and here is the basic code that fails

```
<?php
$db = new SQLite3;
echo $db;
?>
```

**EDIT:**

Code fails by showing the page could not load message on chrome. However, other php code will work fine.

Comment: how does the code "fail"? Do you get an error message, a blank page, what?

Comment: Note the edit please.

Comment: could not load is probably a 500 error. you need to pass a database name to SQLite3 constructor. try: `$db = new SQLite3("database_name"); var_dump($db)`

Comment: I did try it with a database name. The problem is that it doesnt find SQLite3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer:

In php 5.4.x + SQLite3 is not accessable as an object and it has been moved to DBO

solution is [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

This is what worked for me:

```
$dbh = new PDO('sqlite:/tmp/foo.db');
```