# php fatal error: class sqlite3 is not found in

Tags: php, ubuntu, sqlite, ubuntu-12.04, lamp

Im using ubuntu 12.04, and php 5.x I need to use sqlite3 in it but Im getting an error of

```
php fatal error: class sqlite3 not found
```

I done all the installation processes,

like

```
$ sudo apt-get install php5-cli php5-dev make
$ sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-0 libsqlite3-dev
$ sudo apt-get install php5-sqlite3
$ sudo apt-get remove php5-sqlite3
$ cd ~
$ wget http://pecl.php.net/get/sqlite3-0.6.tgz
$ tar -zxf sqlite3-0.6.tgz
$ cd sqlite3-0.6/
$ sudo phpize
$ sudo ./configure
$ sudo make
$ sudo make install
$ sudo apache2ctl restart
```

and

```
cd /etc/php5/conf.d

cat > sqlite3.ini
# configuration for php SQLite3 module
extension=sqlite3.so
^D

sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Now what else I want to do?

Can anyone please help me to fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to enable sqlite3 for php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948899/how-to-enable-sqlite3-for-php)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Found a solution my self,

I installed

```
 $ sudo apt-get install php5-sqlite
```

not

```
 $ sudo apt-get install php5-sqlite3
```

and using sqlite3 class only.. no issue now.

Comment: Whats the difference between sqlite3 and php5-sqlite3? I installed sqlite3 and configured it in php.conf and i still get Class SQLite3 not found

Comment: Basically installing simply sqlite won't do anything if you want to use it with php, you must install php-plugin (I mean extension) for that to make it work with it.

Comment: If you remove the php version # ubuntu will automatically guess the correct #.  
sudo apt-get install php-sqlite3

Comment: Restarting apache2 after installation wasn't enough. Probably the CGI service also requires restarting. I eventually rebooted the system and things worked well.

Answer (score 13):

- Step 1 :

  - For PHP5, use

    ```
    sudo apt-get install php5-sqlite
    ```
  - For PHP7.0, use

    ```
    sudo apt-get install php7.0-sqlite
    ```
  - For PHP7.1, use

    ```
    sudo apt-get install php7.1-sqlite
    ```
  - For PHP7.2, use

    ```
    sudo apt-get install php7.2-sqlite
    ```
  - For PHP7.3, use

    ```
    sudo apt-get install php7.3-sqlite
    ```
- Step 2 :

  - Restart Apache

    ```
    sudo service apache2 restart
    ```

Answer (score 5):

For the error `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'SQLite3' not found in /path/file.php:1` on **ArchLinux**:

Install the sqlite extension for PHP:

```
$ sudo pacman -S php-sqlite
```

Then edit `/etc/php/php.ini` and add:

```
extension=pdo_sqlite
extension=sqlite3
```

Source: [1](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PHP#Sqlite)

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem even I have installed all libraries. 
If you run php-fcgi, you should restart it:

```
sudo service php-fcgi restart
```

Try also restart apache:

```
sudo service apache restart
```

Answer (score 4):

My PHP is 7.3 so I used the following

For PHP7.3, use

```
sudo apt install php7.3-sqlite3
```

And don't forget to restart your **Apache2**

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 4):

In order to install the missing class sqlite3, please run:

```
apt-get install php7.4-sqlite3
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use XAMPP or anything else first close it.

1. Go to this directory: `xampp > php > php.ini` (find this file php.ini on PHP folder)
2. Open php.ini file with notepad
3. Search "SQLite3"
4. Remove ";" this line `;extension=sqlite3`
5. Finally be `extension=sqlite3`
6. Save file
7. Open XAMPP

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. If you are on Windows, don't forget to uncomment `php_sqlite3.dll` (and optionally `php_pdo_sqlite.dll`) extension in `php.ini`. Save `php.ini` and start the script again.

(I added this answer to the question with the `ubuntu` tag because this question is on the first place in google for the request `php sqlite3 not found`).

Answer (score 0):

For php5.6 use:

```
sudo apt-get install php5.6-sqlite3
```

Answer (score 0):

run this command in linux system or (based on your operating system and php versoin )

system info - ubuntu 20
php 7.4
server - php local

```
sudo apt-get install php7.4-sqlite3
```

then you need to restart the your web server app like apache, nginx, or local php server then try to run
you can run the code test sqlite working

```
<?php
   class MyDB extends SQLite3 {
      function __construct() {
         $this->open('sqlitedb.db');
      }
   }
   $db = new MyDB();
   if(!$db) {
      echo $db->lastErrorMsg();
   } else {
      echo "Opened database successfully\n";
   }
?>
```

create php file index.php

i am using php local server
[image]

```
 php -S localhost:8000
```

(http://localhost:8000) open that url
[image]