# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'SQLite3'

Tags: php, database, sqlite

I just tried to create db in php but i got error that says: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'SQLite3' not found in ...

```
$dbhandle = new SQLite3('my_test_db') or die('Unable
to open database');
if (!$dbhandle) die ($sqliteerror);
$stm = "CREATE TABLE Friends(Id integer PRIMARY KEY,"
 "Name text UNIQUE NOT NULL, Sex text CHECK(Sex
IN ('M', 'F')))";
```

tried to remove semicolons before sqlite in php.ini but without success. Does someone know fix ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [php fatal error: class sqlite3 is not found in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19565250/php-fatal-error-class-sqlite3-is-not-found-in)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. Just remove xammp and install wamp.