# Laravel 5.1 : Class 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOSqlite\Driver' not found

Tags: laravel-5.1

I'm using laravel 5.1 , I'm trying to do a migrate:refresh, I get an error :

> Class 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOSqlite\Driver' not found in
>   ../vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/SQLiteConnection.php
>
> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]     Class
>   'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOSqlite\Driver' not found

Doctrine/dbal is already required in my composer.json

```
 "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.1.*",
        "Doctrine/dbal": "^2.5"
    }
```

So I want to ask what is wrong in my laravel project.

Comment: have you set the db's driver at `config/database.php`? Also check your `.env` if you set the values there.

Comment: Have you installed the PHP SQLite package? On Debian, it would be `apt-get install php5-sqlite`. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/948899/2008384).

Comment: @manix what I should change in my .env file https://gist.github.com/morad7/a9e02eb82f3c12e5deaf, the driver is set in database.php https://gist.github.com/morad7/aa99831efe04edbdd7ef

Comment: @Kryten sqlite3 is installed in my ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Did you run a `composer update` after you changed your `composer.json`?

Comment: It has already worked for me, see my answer.

Answer (score 15):

[From the official docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/migrations#dropping-columns):

> Before modifying a column, be sure to add the doctrine/dbal dependency
>   to your composer.json file. The Doctrine DBAL library is used to
>   determine the current state of the column and create the SQL queries
>   needed to make the specified adjustments to the column:
>
> ```
> composer require doctrine/dbal
> ```

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me is to delete the database.sqlite file and create an empty one.
I know this is not the best solution, but it fixed the issue in my use case.

Comment: this is a not good solution. in my case i have data on my tables

Answer (score 0):

Just a heads up, on `Laravel 5.4` (paired with `doctrine/dbal@^2.5` package), using the `Blueprint::dropColumn()` method works like a charm on SQLite databases. No `Class 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOSqlite\Driver' not found` errors thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Doctrine/dbal version 3 doesn't have `Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOSqlite\Driver` class.

Make sure you are using doctrine/dbal version 2.

If you have version 3, you should remove it

```sh
composer remove doctrine/dbal
```

And then to install the version 2

```sh
composer require doctrine/dbal:2.13
```

Visit this link to see all available versions: https://packagist.org/packages/doctrine/dbal