# CodeIgniter\Database\Exceptions\DatabaseException Unable to connect to the database. Main connection [SQLite3]: Class "SQLite3" not found

Tags: php, sqlite, codeigniter, xampp, codeigniter-4

I have a problem, I bought a template on codeigniter 4 Adminto, unpacked it launched the project and I am thrown over localhost to the registration page there is already a test data for login, I click to enter and pops up this error:

```
CodeIgniter\Database\Exceptions\DatabaseException
Unable to connect to the database.
Main connection [SQLite3]: Class "SQLite3" not found
SYSTEMPATH\Database\BaseConnection.php at line 428

421                         break;
422                     }
423                 }
424             }
425 
426             // We still don't have a connection?
427             if (! $this->connID) {
428                 throw new DatabaseException(sprintf(
429                     'Unable to connect to the database.%s%s',
430                     PHP_EOL,
431                     implode(PHP_EOL, $connectionErrors)
432                 ));
433             }
434         }
```

Here is more php spark migrate:

```
Unable to connect to the database.
Main connection [SQLite3]: Class "SQLite3" not found

at SYSTEMPATH\Database\BaseConnection.php:428

Backtrace:
  1    SYSTEMPATH\Database\SQLite3\Connection.php:59
       CodeIgniter\Database\BaseConnection()->initialize()

  2    SYSTEMPATH\Database\BaseConnection.php:575
       CodeIgniter\Database\SQLite3\Connection()->initialize()

  3    SYSTEMPATH\Database\BaseConnection.php:1410
       CodeIgniter\Database\BaseConnection()->query()

  4    SYSTEMPATH\Database\BaseConnection.php:1429
       CodeIgniter\Database\BaseConnection()->listTables()

  5    SYSTEMPATH\Database\MigrationRunner.php:757
       CodeIgniter\Database\BaseConnection()->tableExists()

  6    SYSTEMPATH\Database\MigrationRunner.php:161
       CodeIgniter\Database\MigrationRunner()->ensureTable()

  7    SYSTEMPATH\Commands\Database\Migrate.php:84
       CodeIgniter\Database\MigrationRunner()->latest()

  8    SYSTEMPATH\CLI\Commands.php:65
       CodeIgniter\Commands\Database\Migrate()->run()

  9    SYSTEMPATH\CLI\Console.php:46
       CodeIgniter\CLI\Commands()->run()

 10    ROOTPATH\spark:102
       CodeIgniter\CLI\Console()->run()
```

I tried to comment extension=sqlite3 in the php.ini config file, but it didn't help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to enable sqlite3 for php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948899/how-to-enable-sqlite3-for-php)